# How to debug a flask route with pycharm

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

[image]

I'm looking at https://github.com/ibininja/upload_file_python . I'm working in win 7 with pycharm 2017. The main code contains:

```
@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST"])
def upload():
    folder_name = request.form['superhero']
    '''
    # this is to verify that folder to upload to exists.
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'files/{}'.format(folder_name))):
        print("folder exist")
    '''
    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'files/{}'.format(folder_name))
    print(target)
```

I'd like to debug this in pycharm. I can debug the '/' route as in the screenshot. How do I debug a specific flask route like "/upload" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place a break point at folder_name = request.form['superhero']. Run your whole project in debug mode and when you request the endpoint through postman(its a tool for testing endpoints) you can see your code will stop at that break point.